# How to prove that $ \frac{(99)!!}{(100)!!} < \frac{1}{10}$

Tags: factorial

How to prove that $ \dfrac{(99)!!}{(100)!!}=\dfrac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9 \cdots99}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8\cdot10\cdots100} < \dfrac{1}{10}$

Any hint to prove it?

Comment: By $99!!$ do you mean the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) or the iterated factorial $(99!)!$?

Comment: I mean double factorial

Answer (score 4):

In general the ratio
$$ r_n = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$$
is related to the [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) for which many results are known.

In particular, we have that
$$ (2n-1) (2n-3) \cdots 1 = \frac{(2n) (2n-1)\cdots 1}{(2n)(2n-2) \cdots 2} =2^{-n} \frac{(2n) (2n-1)\cdots 1}{n(n-1) \cdots 1} = 2^{-n} \frac{(2n)!}{n!}$$
and thus
$$ r_n = \frac{(2n-1)(2n-3) \cdots 1}{(2n) (2n-2) \cdots 2}=2^{-n}\frac{(2n-1)(2n-3) \cdots 1}{n (n-1) \cdots 1}=4^{-n} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}  = 4^{-n} \binom{2n}{n}\,.$$

It can be [shown](https://mathoverflow.net/a/133752) that
$$ \binom{2n}{n} \leq \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$
for $n\geq 1$.

Thus, we have that
$$r_n \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$

Specialising for $n=50$, we obtain
$$ \frac{99!!}{100!!} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{50 \pi} } < \frac{1}{\sqrt{144}} = \frac{1}{12} \,.$$

Answer (score 2):

We know that $\dfrac{99!}{100!}=\dfrac{1}{100}$

We rewrite $\dfrac{1}{100}=\dfrac{99!}{100!}=\dfrac{\color{blue}{1}\cdot\color{red}{2}\cdot\color{blue}{3}\cdot\color{red}{4}\cdots\color{red}{98}\cdot\color{blue}{99}}{\color{blue}{1}\cdot\color{red}{2}\cdot\color{blue}{3}\cdot\color{red}{4}\cdots\color{blue}{99}\cdot\color{red}{100}}=\dfrac{99!!\cdot 98!!}{100!!\cdot 99!!}$

We know trivially that both $\frac{99!!}{100!!}$ and $\frac{98!!}{99!!}$ are positive.

Now., there are four possibilities

- both $\frac{99!!}{100!!}$ and $\frac{98!!}{99!!}$ are less than $\frac{1}{10}$, which would lead to a contradiction as their product would be less than $\frac{1}{100}$
- both $\frac{99!!}{100!!}$ and $\frac{98!!}{99!!}$ are greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{10}$, which if at least one is strictly greater than $\frac{1}{10}$ would yield a contradiction as their product would be greater than $\frac{1}{100}$.  If both are equal to $\frac{1}{10}$, then using a prime factorization argument yields a contradiction.
- $\frac{99!!}{100!!}$ is less than $\frac{1}{10}$ and $\frac{98!!}{99!!}$ is greater than $\frac{1}{10}$ (*this is what we want to show must be the case*)
- $\frac{99!!}{100!!}$ is greater than $\frac{1}{10}$ and $\frac{98!!}{99!!}$ is less than $\frac{1}{10}$. (*we want to show this can't be the case*)

So, the question has become proving whether or not $\frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}$ must be less than $\frac{n!!}{(n+1)!!}$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \ln \left( \frac{99!!}{100!!} \right) = \ln \left(\frac{99}{100} \cdot \frac{97}{98} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{50} (\ln(2k-1)- \ln(2k)) $$
with $f(k) = \ln(2k-1)-\ln(2k)$ a concave function of $k$ for $k \ge 1$.
Thus 
$$\eqalign{ \ln \left( \frac{99!!}{100!!} \right) &= \frac{f(1)}{2} + \frac{f(50)}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{49} \frac{f(k)+f(k+1)}{2}\cr
&\le \frac{f(1)}{2} + \frac{f(50)}{2} + \int_1^{50} f(t)\; dt\cr
&= -199 \frac{\ln(2)}{2}-100 \ln(5)+99 \ln(3)+99 \frac{\ln(11)}{2}+\frac{\ln(99)}{2}-\ln(10)\cr &< \ln(1/10)} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$
(2k-1)!! = \frac{(2k-1)!}{2^{k-1}(k-1)!}
$$
$$
(2k)!! = 2^k k!
$$
$$
\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} = \frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}\frac{(2k-1)!}{k!(k-1)!}=\frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}\frac12\frac{2k(2k-1)!}{k!k(k-1)!}=\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\frac{(2k)!}{k!k!}
= \frac{1}{2^{2k}}\binom{2k}{k}
$$
We can express that central binomial coefficient in terms of Catalan numbers:
$$
\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} =  \frac{1}{2^{2k}} (k+1)C_k
$$
The asymptotic form of $C_k$ for $k>2$ is 
$$
\frac{4^k}{k^{3/2}\sqrt{\pi}} (1-\frac{9}{8k}) < C_k <\frac{4^k}{k^{3/2}\sqrt{\pi}} 
$$
So 
$$
\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} < \frac{1}{2^{2k}} (k+1) \frac{4^k}{k^{3/2}\sqrt{\pi}}
= (1+\frac1k)\frac1{\sqrt{k\pi}}
$$
If you plug in $k=33$ this says 
$$\frac{65!!}{66!!} < \frac{34}{33\sqrt{33\pi}} \sim 0.0996 < 0.1$$

And of course $\frac{99!!}{100!!}$ is less than that.